# No app icon when using search bar

Tags: applications, slingshot, app-shortcuts

I've add manually some apps to slingshot menu with .desktop entries.
Everything works fine when I flick through mennu - there is declared icon and declared name. Although, when I start one o these apps, I see my icon in dock.

However, when I use search bar in slingshot and type name of an app then I get this app without icon - only grey square with gearwheel.
It happens only with apps that I added manually to the menu.

How should I fix it? Should I add something in  Desktop Entry?
My desktop entry code is like that:
`[Desktop Entry]
Name=myProgram
Comment=myComment
Exec= myExec
Icon=myIcon
Terminal=false
Type=Application`

Thanks in advance for any help :)
    `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this and see if it helps.

```
sudo apt-get install menulibre
menulibre
```

navigate menulibre to the program that is missing its icon. click on the grey square with gearwheel.

This should open a small menu letting you insert an icon to the shortcut.
Find an icon or suitable picture and see if this removes the grey squares with gearwheels for you.

Answer (score 1):

Menulibre is great when it comes to change desktop icon, but doesn't work every time and sometimes application still has no icon when it's searched from search bar.

I managed to fix these icons with cutting .desktop file from `/usr/share/applications` to another folder; log out; log in; and paste file again into applications folder. :)